# Is it better to get a laptop from your country?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, adapter, laptop

My knowledge about the inner workings of electronics is very limited, but I'm planning to move country that uses a different voltage system and I was wondering if it would matter if I bought a new laptop where I currently am or if it would be better to wait until I move.

Let me explain where I'm coming from --

As far as I know in terms of electronics when you want to use your electrical stuff in a country that has a different voltage system you need to buy a transformer (and an adapter).

From what I know using the transformer should be a temporary solution and not a permanent one.

On laptops the brick that the wire plugs into is the transformer which allows laptops to be used anywhere. What I'm wondering is, is the laptop / transformer specifically set up for the country that it's sold in and it simply has the ability to switch over to other voltages if it needs to (essentially creating the same temporary solution above if used in other countries) or does it always transform voltages no matter where it's used making it not matter where you buy the laptop?

Comment: [Note the bit about shopping recommendations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Read the specs on the power brick. Does it support the voltage system you're moving to? There is the answer to your question.

Comment: Check the laptop's power supply "brick". Does it say 100–240V AC or similar? That's very likely. Also check whether the power supply has a detachable mains cord, because that means you can simply buy a cord matching the power outlets in the country you are moving to.

Comment: As I interpret this, OP is not specifically asking for 'shopping recommendations" so much as they are asking a conceptual question. The last paragraph drives that home, I'm surprised this question got to -3 unless there is more to it.

Comment: @Bort - if it's not shopping then it's "*use* of electronics", which an equally valid close reason. IMO this checks both boxes and clearly indicates that the OP doesn't care what's on or off topic here and the -1's are deserved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most laptop power supplies are universal 100-240V/50-60Hz. Also most of them will have a exchangeable lead which could be bought locally. You can always ask the dealer.

Other concerns with buying a laptop from another country would be warranty issues, keyboard layout, language of installed software, ... etc

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to take into account:

- Voltage difference (mostly 120 or 220-240 V AC). This is clearly shown on your adapter or you can find it in the manual probably. My guess is that most adapters can handle both.
- Plug, as long as the voltage is in spec with your destination country, you can use an adapter plug that fits.

Answer (score 1):

All the laptop power bricks I have seen for a long time are universal voltage, perhaps 100-240V 50-60Hz.  Those will work fine in almost any country.

All you need to do for a more permanent solution is to obtain a mains lead to connect to the power brick that has the correct plug for your local area.

Answer (score 1):

- The adapters used today most of the time support 100-250V and both 50/60Hz. So there is no actual main problem.
- The secondary problem you may encounter may be the plug. If it's not compatible with your area, you'll have to get an adapter or cut the wire and mount a new compatible plug, which is a 5 minute max job for any amateur.

So get it from anywhere, you'll be fine.